# how to use a variable from a superclass to a subclass?

Tags: java, class, variables

I have a superclass and I want to use a variable that is inside this superclass into my subclass. How can this be possible?

Comment: If it is declared `protected`, it will be accessible.

Comment: Read [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html) and [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html) from the Java trails.

Answer (score 16):

Just make the *field* `protected`, meaning that it should be visible to all derived classes.

Answer (score 5):

> I have a superclass and I want to use a variable that is inside this
>   superclass into my subclass. How can this be possible?

If your variable is declared as `protected` or `public` (or) your variable has`default` access privileges(in which case you don't specify with any keyword) and they are in same package(--> You can access it in the subclass directly.
You may use `this` keyword if you are specific.

Example:

```
   public class A{
         protected int field=1;
   } 
   public class B extends A{
         public B(){
             System.out.println(this.field);
         }
         public static void main(String args[]){
           new B();
        }
   }
```

Please note that variable-overriding is not possible. If you have a variable with the same name as in super class then you are out of luck to directly access it. Then you may use `super` keyword.

```
       public class A{
             protected int field=1;
       } 
       public class B extends A{
             protected int field=3;
             public B(){
                 System.out.println(this.field);
                 System.out.println(super.field);
             }
        public static void main(String args[]){
           new B();
        }
       }
```

Comment: There is one more possibility for `super.field`: `((A)this).field`.

Answer (score 2):

If it is public or protected, it should be visible in all methods of the subclass. You can picture it as a `global variable` in the subclass.